# Understanding probabilities on continuous sample spaces more difficult than uniform probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, borel-sets

Let $[c,d]$ be a subset or $\mathbb R$. On $\mathscr B([c,d])$ we define the probability $P$ such as

$$P(I)=\frac{b-a}{d-c} $$ if $I$ is a Borelian with lower and upper bound $a$ and $b$

I call this probability the *uniform probability* (but maybe it's not appropriate..).

Could you provide other examples of probabilities on a continuous sample space, different from the *uniform probability*?

Especially I notice that if $\Omega=\mathbb R$, the uniform probability cannot work on $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$. What is the probability corresponding?

PS: I am having a headaching hard time to see the link between the sample space and the event space in the case of a continuous sample space. I've read some stuff on the *probability distributions*, but as far as I understand it is related to the event space of a R.V.

Also, I have the feeling that most of the time the R.V. is simply $X: \omega \rightarrow \omega$, is it correct ?

Lastly, is it also the case in the continuous case that the pre-image of the Random Variable partitions the sample space? (as it was the case in discrete spaces)

Comment: Many continuous distributions are ibtained by taking any measurable nonnegative $f$ that integrates to $1$ and setting $P(A) = \int_{A}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Ok but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Absolutely_continuous_probability_distribution) and many other sites, the probability distribution $f$ is defined as $$P(X\in A)=\int _{A} f(x)dx$$ Your definition which is the one I find most natural, defines a probability **on the sample space** (invoking as you did a function $f$). The problem is that your function $f$ and the prob. distribution from Wikipedia are not necessarily the same. I'll write in a second comment why they are not necessarily the same...

Comment: Here's an example where your $f$ and the proba. distribution from Wiki are not the same. Take: $$  X(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
\omega,  & \text{if $\omega \in [0,0.5]$} \\
\omega -0.5, & \text{if $\omega \in [0.5,1]$}
\end{cases}$$
Sample space is $[0,1]$ and let's say $P$ on the Samp. space is uniform (Your $f$ is $Id$). Then $$P(X\in [0,0.1]) = P([0,0.1]\cup[0.5,0.6]) =0.2$$ But (Wiki says) $$P(X\in A)=\int _A g(x)dx$$ So, with $A=[0,0.1]$ we have $g=2\times Id$ Hence, $$g\neq f$$

Comment: In my example you take $X(\omega) = \omega$. Then $P(A) = P(X \in A)$. Thus I have constructed a probability space and a random variable $X$ with density $f$. What is on Wikipedia is not a definition of a probability distribution, rather it defines what it means for $X$ to have density $f$.